# Is there a physical (electronics) difference between Hue White and Color and Hue White Ambiance bulbs?

Tags: led, rgb, lighting

I'm curious if anyone knows if there's a physical difference between a Philips Hue White and Color bulb, which allows the user to set a complete range of RGB colors including white light color temperature, and the Philips Hue White Ambiance bulb, which only allows the user to set the color temperature of the "white" light?

Can Philips use a simpler controller in the electronics or simpler/cheaper LEDs for the white-only bulb?  Or are they simply charging more for the added functionality (lines of code) of setting a complete range of RGB values versus a "color temperature" subset?

Comment: Do you have both of them? Can you take them apart?

Comment: I'd guess that the 'shades of white' bulb may have only two types of white LED with differing phosphors (one yellowish, one fairly blue) rather than the full set of RGBW LEDs.